# What should I do in OpsCenter after deleting the cassandra superuser?

Tags: datastax-enterprise, opscenter

After building a DSE cluster with Opscenter, I cannot configure after deleting the cassandra user.
I see an error code that Opscenter is trying to log in to the DSE cluster with the cassandra user.
What operation should I do in Opscenter after deleting the cassandra user?
Please tell me.

Comment: Hopefully, you created  other superusers before deleting the cassandra user?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a lot of information and I don't know what the problem is exactly but I'm going to assume that you [enabled authentication](https://docs.datastax.com/en/security/6.8/security/Auth/secEnableDseAuthenticator.html) on your DSE cluster.

In order to disable or drop the default `cassandra` superuser role, you need another superuser role to do that so I take it you've [created a new superuser role](https://docs.datastax.com/en/security/6.8/security/Auth/secCreateRootAccount.html).

Using the new superuser role, you need [to create separate logins for users and applications](https://docs.datastax.com/en/security/6.8/security/secRBAC.html). You should create a separate service account for OpsCenter. Once you've done that, you need to [update the cluster connection properties](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.8/opsc/configure/opscConnectionConfig_r.html) in `clusters/cluster_name.conf` on the OpsCenter with the new credentials:

```
[cassandra]
username = opsc_svc_account
password = opsc_svc_account_password
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I was following your procedure.
However, after restarting Opscenter, Opscenter still tries to log in as the cassandra user.

jobs status:Verifying the password for DSE user 'cassandra'

Is there anything else I need to configure?

Comment: Without looking at the logs and your configuration, it's impossible for me to comment. You can workaround it by removing the cluster from OpsCenter then add it back in. If that doesn't work, I'd suggest logging a ticket with https://support.datastax.com so one of our engineers can assist you directly. Cheers!